# ArgumentType: 'Big Decimal' does not match the type of the format specified '%d'

Tags: java, string, object, bigdecimal, string.format

```
String stockStr = " ";

for (StockRecordDTO stockNumber : stockID)
{
    stockStr+= 

    String.format("the stock %s for Date %s with Quantity %d ", 
            stockNumber.getStock(),
            stockNumber.getBusinessDate(), 
            stockNumber.getQuantity()
        );
}
```

I am trying to print out an ArrayList of values by extracting it to a string and then printing it this way. I am getting the Values from a DTO class, and I'm getting an error with the `string.format` method I have used saying

> ArgumentType: 'Big Decimal' does not match the type of the format specified '%d'

Quantity is defined as a BIG Decimal in DTO class.

So how do I solve this?

Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: You can use `%s` instead of `%d` .

Comment: You are just printing the value not doing any manipulation (any mathematical operation) on `stockNumber.getQuantity()`, so you can go ahead with @Eritrean's comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try to convert the `BigDeciaml` to a `double`:

```
stockNumber.getQuantity().doubleValue()
```

Be careful with that, there might be a reason to use `BigDeciamal` in you class and converting it to a different type might lead to loss of precision.

Comment: Converting to double will fail with the same error unless you change also the format specifier to `%f` . No need to convert to to another type. Using `%s` is enough.

Comment: Will that affect the value that is outputed/ affect the precision of the value?

Comment: @ShiBui it can affect the precision of the value. `BigDecimal` can represent (almost) arbitrarily large numbers with (almost) arbitrarily large precision. The limits of `BigDecimal` are way much bigger than the limits of `double`. Depending on your data it is possible that the values that you use fit into a `double` - but then is the question why the code uses `BigDecimal` in the first place.